# Magento2 after comment added observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I need an observer to be executed when I add a new comment to an order. On Magento 1.9 I used sales_order_save_after event but it does not exist on M2 anymore.

Anyone can help me with an event to do that or any idea to solve this ?

Basically the observer reads the new comment, looks for some content, if it is found it executes some code.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an observer, you could add an after plugin to the addCommentToStatusHistory function in vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php

There you could retrieve the comment added and execute your function if the comment match your content.

```
public function afterAddCommentToStatusHistory($subject, $result,$comment, $status , $isVisibleOnFront )
{
    if($comment=='something'){
       doSomething();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Reference for plugin creation : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Great idea :) Let me test it and I will get back to you... thanks :D

Comment: It looks like it solve my problem. Sorry for taking long, too much work here. Thank you !